# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s in cocos2dx ios

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x

I am getting these linker errors

```
cocos2d::CCLayer::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet*, cocos2d::CCEvent*)", referenced from:
vtable for Splash in Splash.o
"non-virtual thunk to cocos2d::CCLayer::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet*,  
cocos2d::CCEvent*)",         referenced from:
vtable for Splash in Splash.o
"cocos2d::CCSize::CCSize(cocos2d::CCSize const&)", referenced from:
Collision::isCollision() in Collision.o
"cocos2d::CCArray::count() const", referenced from:...and many more linker errors
```

I am using xcode 5.1 and cocos2dx 2.2
When i am removing armv7s then i am able to archive but i am not able to run the game on my iphone 5s which has ios7.1. but on lower versions its gud..
If i add armv7s architecture then i am not able to run on lower versions and none of the device..I am getting again linker errors

By adding it unable to archive the game. with some error that q0 register not found..
If there a way to fix

Comment: Make sure you add armv7s to all targets of the project, not just the app target if there are multiple targets. Also update both "Architectures" and "Valid Architectures" under Build Settings.

Comment: yes i did it.I have 2 targets.one cocos2dx and another is my game. But when i am making a build in iphone5 which has latest updated ios7.1.it is throwing around 200 linker errors regarding the architecture.I really couldn't figure out

Answer (score 0):

I have this running and I have: armv6 armv7 i386 as my Valid Architectures with a Base SDK of iOS 7.1.

Comment: pls put armv7s architecture also and then archieve and build